# Parsing through data using Pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, database, facebook

I'm trying to create testing data from my facebook messages but Im having some issues.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3
import os
import json
import datetime
import re

folder_path = 'C:\\Users\\Shipt\\Desktop\\chatbot\\data\\messages\\inbox'
db = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
cursor = db.cursor()
data = {'text': [], 'handle_id': [], 'is_from_me': [], 'date': []}
other_participant = ''


for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder_path):
    for dir in dirs:
        # Get a list of all the JSON files in the subdirectory
        json_files = [f for f in os.listdir(
            os.path.join(root, dir)) if f.endswith('.json')]

        # Loop through the JSON files
        for json_file in json_files:
            with open(os.path.join(root, dir, json_file), 'r', encoding='iso-8859-1') as f:
                json_data = f.read().encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8-sig')
                json_data = json.loads(json_data)

        # Check that its not a gc cause thats too hard rn #imdumb #defeated
            if len(json_data['participants']) != 2:
                continue

         # Extract the required data from the JSON object
            messages = json_data['messages']
            partcipants = json_data['participants']

          # Do something with the data

            for participant in partcipants:
                try:
                    # this should be the participant who isnt me right
                    other_participant = participant[0]
                    print(other_participant)

                except (KeyError):
                    continue
            for message in messages:
                try:
                    # removes emojis
                    content = re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7F]+', '', message['content'])
                    data['text'].append(content)
                    # uses binary to flag if it was sent by me or not
                    who_from = (message['sender_name'])
                    if who_from == 'Josh Shipton':
                        data['is_from_me'].append(1)
                    else:
                        data['is_from_me'].append(0)

                    data['handle_id'].append(other_participant)

                    # converts the weird timestamp fb gives into normal data
                    timestamp_ms = message['timestamp_ms']
                    date_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(
                        timestamp_ms/1000.0)
                    data['date'].append(date_time)

                except (KeyError):
                    continue


df = pd.DataFrame(data)
# making masks to fix data
mask = (df['text'].str.lower().str.split().str[1] == 'reacted') | (
    df['text'].str.lower().str.split().str[0] == 'reacted')
df = df.loc[~mask]
mask = df['text'].str.contains('Liked a message')
df = df.loc[~mask]

# testing code
file_path = 'to_see_data.txt'
with open(file_path, 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(df.to_csv(header=False, index=False))


df.dropna(subset=['text'], inplace=True)


def make_sentences(series):
    return '. '.join(series)


train_data = pd.DataFrame(columns=['text', 'response'])

# iterate thru each convo
for person in pd.unique(df['handle_id']):
    # goes through one person at a time
    conversation = df[df['handle_id'] == person]
    # groups the data by rows when the "is_from_me" changes. applies the "make sentences" function to concate the repeated messages into single sentences
    grouped = (conversation.groupby(conversation.is_from_me.diff().ne(0).cumsum(), as_index=False)
               .agg({'text': make_sentences, 'is_from_me': 'first',
                     'handle_id': 'first', 'date': 'first'}))

    tmp = pd.DataFrame({'text': list(conversation['text'][0:-1]),
                        'response': list(conversation['text'][1:])})

    train_data = pd.concat(
        [train_data, tmp[['text', 'response']]], ignore_index=True)

# make lowercase
train_data['text'] = train_data['text'].apply(lambda x: x.lower())
train_data['response'] = train_data['response'].apply(lambda x: x.lower())

# testing code
file_path = 'train_data.txt'
with open(file_path, 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(train_data.to_csv(header=False, index=False))

train_data.to_sql('chatbot', db, if_exists='replace', index=False)

# Read the data from the database to confirm that it was written correctly
df = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM chatbot', db)
# print(df.head())
print('doneski')
```

pretty much the 'make_sentences' function is not working and right now every single reply is being shown in the text-reply db. I want to get the code to only show my responses (with the binary flag of 1) in the response column and the text that i responded to in the "text" column without any duplicates. Any help would be greatly appreciated. cheers

I've tried changing the code around and using different tmp dataframes with different parameters ive also tried filtering the messages so that only the messages from the other person were shown.

Comment: `make_sentences` is: `'. '.join(series)` - so it's not clear how this is the problem? You don't seem to be masking by `df['is_from_me'] == 1` anywhere in the code if you only want those rows?